# Java: Mock testing probably with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I think I'm not using `verify` correctly. Here is the test:

```
@Mock GameMaster mockGM;    
Player pWithMock;

@Before
public void setUpPlayer() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    pWithMock = new Player(mockGM);
}

@Test
    public void mockDump() {
        pWithMock.testDump();
        verify(mockGM).emitRandom(); // fails
    }
```

Here is the code it calls:

```
public boolean testDump() {
    Letter t = tiles.getRandomTile();
    return dump(t);
}

private boolean dump(Letter tile) {
            if (! gm.canTakeDump() || tiles.count() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    tiles.remove(tile);
    gm.takeTile(tile);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tiles.addTile(gm.emitRandom()); // this is the call I want to verify
    }
    return true;
}
```

Failure trace:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
gameMaster.emitRandom();
-> at nth.bananas.test.PlayerTest.mockDump(PlayerTest.java:66)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at nth.bananas.Player.dump(Player.java:45)

    at nth.bananas.test.PlayerTest.mockDump(PlayerTest.java:66)
```

The call I want to verify is several layers down. Is there a different way to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your test method: it's missing a necessary expectation for the `GameMaster#canTakeDump()`. This method needs to return `true` when called from the tested method (because of its use in that `if` statement at line 45).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you are doing. Given the following `Player` class:

```
public class Player {
    private final GameMaster gm;

    public Player(GameMaster gameMaster) {
        this.gm = gameMaster;
    }

    public void foo() {
        gm.bar(); // this is the call we want to verify
    }
}
```

And the following `GameMaster` class:

```
public class GameMaster {
    public GameMaster() {
    }

    public void bar() {
    }
}
```

I'd write the test of `Player` like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PlayerTest {

    @Mock
    private GameMaster gm;

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        Player player = new Player(gm);
        player.foo();
        verify(gm).bar(); // pass
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely don't know what I'm doing. How is this different from what I posted?

Comment: also, what if the GameMaster class doesn't have a constructor with no args?

Comment: @Rosarch *How is that different?* I'm not totally sure as you didn't show all code but, well, this works :) *What if the GameMaster doesn't have a constructor with no args?* Well, this is a sample but if you need to add this constructor to make the code testable, just do it.

Comment: ok, but in your example, what if `foo()` calls `odp()`, which then calls `bar()`. Would `verify(gm).bar()` still detect it?

Comment: I'm not sure of what `opd()` does but you may need to create a full graph of mocks if this is your question.

Comment: `odp()` does nothing but call `bar()`. `void odp() { gm.bar();}`

Comment: @Rosarch Isn't that precisely what `foo()` is doing? I don't get the difference.

Comment: Right, but `foo()` isn't calling `bar()` directly, whereas `odp()` is.

Comment: I don't think I'm still following you and, because I can't reproduce your test, I don't think we'll solve this using the commenting system. Maybe you should post something that readers could reproduce, this would help IMO.